# How to compile 32bit x86 application in 64bit x86 environment?

Tags: c++, c, linux

How to compile 32bit x86 application in 64bit x86 environment?

Any command for cc/ld/ar, including options? Thanks.

Any links is well appreciated. Thanks.

Note: take c code for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just use `-m32` and make sure that you have all the 32 bit tools and libraries installed (not all x86-64 distros include these by default, so you may need to `apt-get` or `yast` or whatever to install these).

```
$ gcc -m32 -Wall foo.c -o foo
```

Comment: OK, Thanks Paul R. How about reverse question? build 64 bit app in 32bit env?  use -m64 right?

Comment: `-m64` wil work in an x86-64 environment (but it's the default anyway). I don't know of any 32 bit x86 environments that support building 64 bit x86-64 code though.

Comment: @PaulR any decent 32-bit linux distro will ship a multilib compiler, just like a 64-bit edition would.

Comment: @rubenvb: OK - thanks - I didn't know that - I haven't used a 32 bit x86 distro for quite a few years now.

Answer (score 3):

To compile and link a C source file with a 64-bit multilib GCC, you can do the following:

```
gcc -m32 -c somefile.c
gcc -m32 somefile.o -o myprog
```

Note that all 32-bit libraries need to be installed and useable by the multilib compiler.

`ar` should work, if built correctly, it is discouraged to call `ld` directly, because its options are radically different from GCC's. Just link with GCC.

---

As to why it is "discouraged to call `ld` directly": If you all `gcc` to link, it will know exactly where system/runtime libraries are located, and also about any platform-specific options it needs to pass to `ld`. When calling `ld` directly, you need to take care of all of that. Here that matters for the options for 32 vs 64-bit, along with proper library directories.

Comment: "it is discouraged to call ld directly" why any more explanation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `-m32` flag is all you need, ie.

```
gcc -m32 ...
```

If you get an error, you may need the 32-bit libraries, that might be named similar to `glibc-devel.i686`. That's the name of the package on Fedora (using `yum`), other Linux distros should be similar.

On Debian & Ubuntu, you'll need the `gcc-multilib` and `ia32-libs-dev`  packages.

Comment: How about ubuntu x86_64 env, Is there any command available for installing x86_32 libs, such as sudo apt-get install XXXX?

Comment: @Daniel: Apparently there's a `g++-multilib` package, check [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers#A32-bit_Builds_on_AMD64) for more details.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Thanks a lot, I'll keep those noted down for reference in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I needed -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 sometimes -m32 makes some trouble sometimes so you have to try yourself.

```
c++ -m32 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 foo.c -o foo
```

But that's for the other way round. Compiling 64bit programs on 32bit boxes.

Comment: -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 ? some thing like a macro definition: _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64.

Comment: @Daniel: No, it's an option. But I fixed my answer. My problem was the opposite of your problem.

Comment: I see. -m32 solve the question. The MACRO seems solve some program issues NOT cc/ld/ar problem, is that right?

Comment: @Daniel: The macro helps me to solve a pread invalid argument error when I try to read from a device file.